# Laptop screen flickering on HP Laptop

Tags: kubuntu, display, amd-processor

Ok. So I'm running a fresh install of Kubuntu 17.10.1 on my Laptop, then 5 minutes later, the screen starts flickering and eventually stops responding. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've already tried changing the compositor and vsync settings and no luck. I'm running an AMD E2 APU. I'm using this computer for schoolwork too. I don't want to damage my eyes. Please help.

My computer model is HP 14-bw0xx, if you need that.
Edit: Updating the amd graphics drivers seemed to help for a while, until I closed firefox. Then it started again.

Second edit: OK my installation completely died. All I have on my screen is a white rectangle in the corner and a grey bar on the bottom. This happened because i installed some more drivers from AMDs website. When i click, it shuts down then reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're having driver issues, could you try booting up Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB stick and check if you're still experiencing the problem?

(Doesn't matter whether it's `Kubuntu` or `Ubuntu` here, and btw - checking your computer's characteristics makes me think that `Lubuntu` might be better for you in the end, since it's desktop environment is `LXDE`, which is lighter on your computer's resources)

Maybe a lower kernel (Ubuntu `16.04` has **4.04**, `17.10` has **4.13**) would work with your hardware.

Comment: I updated the drivers and it worked for a while. Check the edit in the original post.

Comment: I see. I meant that you might need older drivers / an older kernel that are compatible with you HP model. 17.10 is actually not an LTS release, so updating your drivers or even trying it out maybe isn't a great idea. Had such issues myself before, most recently with my Elantech touchpad.

Could you please try 16.04 instead of 17.10, and not update your drivers? Just need to see whether that would solve some of the issues.

Comment: I just tried 16.04, and it flashes even more now. I also tried other linux distros and the screen flashed with them too. I have no idea what is going on. I think it's my computer that's causing the problem now, because when I installed Ubuntu on other PCs, it didn't flash the screen. I also tried changing the refresh rate in the settings, and no help.